# Exception for Threads in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm new to python and I'm trying to compare the Exceptions in ADA and Python.
While doing so I faced an issue.

In ADA there is a built in Exception called `Task_error` which handles the tasks (which are threads in python).
`Task_error` handles the communication problems between tasks in ADA.

What is the Exception that handles the communication errors among tasks in python?

I have gone through some documentation but could not find it helpful.
Can anyone please help me??

Comment: There is no single exception for inter-thread communication in python. Have you tried using queues to communicate between threads? If so, there are specific exceptions to queue handling. If you're using shared memory, there are exceptions for that as well. If you have a specific problem to solve, this forum is more useful for that type of inquiry.

Comment: Well, I don't have a specific problem to solve using python. But I just want to compare the ADA and python built in exception handling